# Where to install water shutoff valve

Tags: plumbing, copper, shutoff, cpvc

I'm remodeling a bathroom in a house built in 1993 (Midwest USA). Apparently the plumbers didn't add shutoff valves under the main or master bathroom sinks... I've found plenty of instructions online for how to add a compression shutoff valve, but the plumbing under the sink goes from CPVC to copper, so I'm not sure if I should really install the fitting on the copper.

My question is; Should I install the shutoff on the copper?

Or should I use a CPVC specific shutoff and take the copper off completely?

My impression is that installing a compression fitting on the copper would be easier, but I don't know if that would be up to code in this situation.

[image: plumbing under vanity sink]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave the copper attached to the CPVC, *if taint broke don't fix it*.

I would cut it down a little so your new valves are not so high, just below the drain pipe.
You can use compression, solder or push to connect valves for 1/2" copper.

I would add support for the pipes,  put a piece of wood horizontal on the wall and use copper pipe standoff's or straps to secure the pipes and keep them from flexing when using the valves.

Comment: Good advice, especially the bracing.  Last thing you want is to worry about ripping it to pieces as you try to turn that stubborn little valve 10 years from now.